# Check the number of parameters from state_dict in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

SO has an answer about how to check the total # of params from the model:
`pytorch_total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())`

However, how does one check the total # of params from
the `state_dict`?

`state_dict = torch.load(model_path, map_location='cpu')`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can count the number of saved entries in the state_dict:

```py
sum(p.numel() for p in state_dict.values())
```

However, there's a snag here: a state_dict stores both [parameters](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/nn.html#parameters) *and* [persistent buffers](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer) (e.g., BatchNorm's running mean and var). There's no way (AFAIK) to tell them apart from the state_dict itself, you'll need to load them into the model and use `sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters()` to count only the parameters.

For instance, if you checkout [`resnet50`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/torchvision/models.html#torchvision.models.resnet50)

```py
from torchvision.models import resnet50
model = resnet50(pretrained=True)
state_dict = torch.load('~/.torch/models/resnet50-19c8e357.pth')
num_parameters = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
num_state_dict = sum(p.numel() for p in state_dict.values())
print('num parameters = {}, stored in state_dict = {}, diff = {}'.format(num_parameters, num_state_dict, num_state_dict - num_parameters))
```

Resulting with

> ```
> num parameters = 25557032, stored in state_dict = 25610152, diff = 53120
> ```

As you can see there can be quite a gap between the two values.